# Slick slider вертикальный слайдер

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

надо чтобы элементы слайдера двигались сверху вниз. 
По дефолту они движутся снизу в верх, и я не знаю как поправить это

```
   $(".block").slick({
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: true,
    vertical: true,
    autoplay:true,
    autoplaySpeed:2000,
    verticalSwiping: true
});
```

Comment: нет там настроек таких похоже. как вариант просто не использовать автоскролл, а повесить ручную переключалку по таймеру да и все.

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".slickPrev").slick("slickPrev");

}, 2000);
```